# 2016 Sending html across to a server

Tags: javascript, html, encoding

I'm grabbing web page data (think similar issue to [instapaper](http://www.2ality.com/2011/01/javascript-hack-send-current-web-page.html)) and sending it back to a LOCAL server, not across the web. Both will be on the same machine, but I'd still like to make it a bit more secure.

I'd currently grabbing html from webpages and attempting to encode it into a URI. Here's the problem. The built in function `encodeURI` doesn't work properly because some content inside a HTML page is already encoded, and some of it isn't! Like the HTML itself. Let me give an example from a ([decades old website that still exists](http://youvegotmail.warnerbros.com/cmp/0frameset.html)).

This code:

`<title>You've Got Mail</title>` needs to be encoded to: `"%3Ctitle%3EYou've%20Got%20Mail%3C/title%3E"`

But some of it comes in pre-encoded (before `encodeURI` is called):

`<noframes>
&lt;body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" background="../img/1bgbottom.gif" text="#000000" link="#2100c5" vlink="#2100c5" alink="#bd0031"&gt;`

Is there any simple way to take an HTML page (in all it's ugliness) and encode it in a URI reliably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `encodeURIComponent()`.  There's never really a good reason (that I know of anyway) for `encodeURI()`.

Once you use `encodeURIComponent()`, it can be decoded as-is, getting you exactly what was sent in.

On another note, I'm not sure where you're doing this encoding but if you plan to use this in a query string, beware that there are finite query string limits, usually 4k or 64k.  (At least sometimes you can configure the limit server-side.)

Comment: can't you just encode as base64? p.s. if you hit query string length limit with GET method, you can always switch to POST and send all the data.

Comment: @LukasLiesis Sure, base64 is another way which will guarantee binary compatibility at a 33% overhead.